# I can't get images to print to screen with the PHP QR Code library

Tags: php, png, qr-code

I've been playing with [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net) all day and I can’t seem to get a QR code to actually print to screen. I’ve read through the documentation and I’ve tried a few different methods I found online but I just can't get a QR code to output to the screen. Here’s the code I'm using per the instructions in the documentation:

```
 <?php

 header("Content-type: image/png");
 include ("phpqrcode/qrlib.php");
 QRcode::png('some othertext 1234');


 ?>
```

According to the documentation this code should output a QR code which would give the text inside the parentheses.

Comment: I thought Id add that I just need to figure out how to get it to output correctly. Ive seen the google api that outputs qrcodes but I dont want to use that on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set your headers so your browser knows to render the QR code as an image?

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

If you are setting your header (or phpqrcode does it for you, I can't remember) but you're not getting the image, see if you are getting any php errors or warnings that are inadvertently echoing out in the output stream, that will cause problems rendering your image. Ditto for any other chars you may be accidentally outputting.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :)  I do have that in my code....I resubmitted my question up above to reflect how I have it inserted. Also I dont have any errors related to the phpqrcode library.

Comment: Did you look at the raw response to see if there is anything other than the png data? You may be seeing something like this: `PHP Warning: blah blah blah âPNG IHDR’FásBIT...` which won't render.

Comment: would raw responses be somewhere else besides the php error log?

Comment: IIRC error reporting and error logging are controlled by different settings in php.ini. What happens if you use cURL or fiddler (or some other tool) to examine the raw data coming back from the server?

Comment: Ive never used either of those myself. I usually stick to doing c++ or java for mobile development so this is my first venture into something like this. Ill go ahead and try to use one of them. Which one do you think is easier to set up.

Comment: On win, I use fiddler, on mac I use Charles web proxy. Basically you run the app and you can see each http request on your client and inspect each one.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip I just set up the fiddler and Im trying to figure out how to see the data from the page.

Comment: what would I be looking for in the rawdata section

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6566/discussion-between-m-m-and-james-andresakis)

Answer (score -1):

If you use linux, try installing this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

linux's xampp wont generate .png because this apt not installed